# Create app with image from own docker registry on OpenShift 3.1

Tags: docker, docker-registry, openshift-origin

I have my own docker registry secured with a selfsigned certificate.
On other servers, I'm able to login on the registry and pull/push images from it. So that seems to work fine.

But when I want to create an app from the image using OpenShift it does not seem te work:

```
oc new-app ec2-xxx:5000/test/image1
error: can't look up Docker image "ec2-xx/test/image1": Internal error occurred: Get https://ec2-xxx:5000/v2/: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
error: no match for "ec2-xxx:5000/test/image1"
```

What could be the issue?
I'm able to login in the registry and pull the image manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding "--insecure-registry" to new-app command

oc new-app ec2-xxx:5000/test/image1 --insecure-registry

Comment: But the registry is secure? (I'm using selfsigned ssl certs)

Comment: As you are using self signed certificates (not signed by a trusted aurhority), openshift can' t verify the identity of your registro.

Comment: And what when I'm using the ca.crt of openshift itself (I have secured my openshift registry)